# Typescript response select data

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-mvc, typescript

HMy html is displaying undefined(undefined), I can see the data in the debugger, so I am not sure if I am not using the select data correct?
HTML View

```
<div *ngIf="publishItemsWarningMessage" class="text-danger">
    {{publishItemsWarningMessage}}
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let detail of publishItemsWarningMessageDetails">
            {{detail}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Typescript

```
if (response.UnpublishedRelatedTemplates.length > 0) {
    this.publishItemsWarningMessageDetails = Enumerable
        .From(response.UnpublishedRelatedTemplates)
        .Select(UnpublishedRelatedTemplates => response.UnpublishedRelatedTemplates.RelatedTemplateId + " (" + response.UnpublishedRelatedTemplates.TemplateId + ")")
        .ToArray();
}
```

debug

[image]

UI display undefined (undefined)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your `Typescript` code like below. Replace `response.UnpublishedRelatedTemplates` with `UnpublishedRelatedTemplates` inside `.Select(...)`

```
if (response.UnpublishedRelatedTemplates.length > 0) {
    this.publishItemsWarningMessageDetails = Enumerable
        .From(response.UnpublishedRelatedTemplates)
        .Select(UnpublishedRelatedTemplates => UnpublishedRelatedTemplates.RelatedTemplateId + " (" + UnpublishedRelatedTemplates.TemplateId + ")")
        .ToArray();
}
```

**Explanation**
You are getting `undefined` because inside `Select` you are using `response.UnpublishedRelatedTemplates.RelatedTemplateId` but `response.UnpublishedRelatedTemplates` is an `array` so it will not have `RelatedTemplateId`. Instead you can use `index` `[index]` to get value like `response.UnpublishedRelatedTemplates[index].RelatedTemplateId`.

But as you are already `Enumerating` on your array so `UnpublishedRelatedTemplates` will hold value of `response.UnpublishedRelatedTemplates[index]`. So you can simply replace it.

Try it below

```js
let response = {
  UnpublishedRelatedTemplates: [{
    RelatedTemplateId: 'TMRelated2',
    TemplateId: 'TMRelated1'
  }, {
    RelatedTemplateId: 'TMDummy2',
    TemplateId: 'TMDummy1'
  }]
};

if (response.UnpublishedRelatedTemplates.length > 0) {
  let publishItemsWarningMessageDetails = Enumerable
    .From(response.UnpublishedRelatedTemplates)
    .Select(UnpublishedRelatedTemplates => UnpublishedRelatedTemplates.RelatedTemplateId + " (" + UnpublishedRelatedTemplates.TemplateId + ")")
    .ToArray();

  console.log(publishItemsWarningMessageDetails);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.min.js" integrity="sha256-dq1fzSor46Oc+U/DjuE2hKKN0FfvbVx+CW5GBn1mhiQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I am getting RelatedTemplateId  does not exist on type unknow?

Comment: I guess it will be solved if you declare correct type of `UnpublishedRelatedTemplates`. Suppose type is `T` then rewrite `Select` as `.Select((UnpublishedRelatedTemplates: T) => UnpublishedRelatedTemplates.RelatedTemplateId + " (" + UnpublishedRelatedTemplates.TemplateId + ")")`.